# How do i call a function every day between 10 am to 11 am

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create a function in c# and published on server. But now i want to run this function between 10am to 11am only. How can i create this?

Comment: Compile your function in a program and use Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Have you tried google it first? You may want to check this : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/06e64804-23ca-49d1-be3a-5c6d28becc94/

Comment: @DanAbramov he may not be able to use Windows Task Scheduler if he hosts Asp.net website on other private server.

Comment: You should code windows service.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest would be to use a [Windows Task](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Working-Windows-Server-2008-Task-Scheduler-Part1.html), here's an exemplary trigger which should do what you want:

[image]

( asuming Windows because of the ASP.NET tag )

Answer (score 2):

Use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to schedule your process to run.  Or, if you really mean call a specific method: write a console application that calls that specific method and schedule it with task scheduler

**Edit**

In case you're not running a Windows environment, here's the man page for [cron](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/cron/). You can schedule a job to kick off a Mono process (or if you just need to access a page to call your method maybe a [shell script](http://freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch02.html) that calls [wget](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/wget.1.php))

Comment: How do you know the server is windows?

Comment: That's a good point, updating with information on cron

Comment: @CasparKleijne: It's rather likely because of the ASP.NET tag.

Comment: @CasparKleijne the answer has been updated to include task scheduling on Linux

Answer (score 1):

Start use [Quartz .Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

with help of [Cron Maker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It should be an answer what is in the comments:

Use the windows task scheduler. With [PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa973757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you should be able to call into any .NET assembly you write.